# Display only unique page numbers in Table of Content

Tags: table-of-contents

Currently, my Table of Contents looks like this:
[image]

However, I feel like having so many repeating page numbers looks a bit weird. What I want it to look like is this:

[image]

I have generated the Table of Contents with:

```
\tableofcontents
```

Also, this is the first academic document that I have written so I am open to suggestions as to why this might not be a good idea.

Thank you!

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would reset the TOC depth. Your TOC should only have chapters (and sections if necessary), but not subsections.

Comment: I'd not do like that: either remove subsections from the TOC or leave the page numbers.

Comment: An alternative would be to make the first instance of a page boldface.

Comment: @JouleV I think you are right! I will limit the TOC only to chapters and sections. But just out of curiosity - how would you do what I wanted to do initially?

Comment: @IvanPanchev Add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` to the preamble. If you want to understand what it means, just change `1` to `0` or `2` :)